# show all files of a specific path in a view in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

let me explain the scenario:
1. I have created a content type "fileupload" and uploaded 4 files in a specific directory (amitfile).
2. Now I want to create a view that will show all the files of that directory (amitfile) in a table with name and uploaded date.

please help me how to do this is drupal.

Comment: Do you want a view (Drupal view) or just a listing of files in admin interface ??

Comment: thanks for commenting, i want a view. I tried by doing a relationship, but files are showing redundantly. for example, if the directory has 4 files, in view. i am getting 16 files!

Comment: if i get you right, the "directory" amitfile is a directory in the file system?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually create a view listing exclusively files.

`Structure > Views > Add new view` and select `Show: Files` instead of `Content`.

After creating the view you can add **filter criteria** to filter by `File: Path`. There select `Operator: Contains` and `Value: amitfile`.

You might want to add other filters such as `File: Status` or `File Usage: Entity type`